# How to create dynamic metric in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, metrics

I want to create one metric related to the number of errors but in fact I would like to add some contextual labels ?
What is the best way to do that ? gauge ?
How to create this kind of metric dynamically during the run of the task (because open method is not possible because too early) ?
Thanks in advance

David

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a metric whenever you want -- just do it once per operator instance, before you use it.

For error reporting you might find [side outputs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html) useful as well.

Comment: Thanks David. Yes definitely side outputs fits perfectly and it can be used with appropriate sinks.