# How to use multiple counters in Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, metrics

(kinda related to [How to create dynamic metric in Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56694833/how-to-create-dynamic-metric-in-flink))

I have a stream of `events(someid:String, name:String)` and for monitoring reasons, I need a counter **per** event ID.
In all the Flink documentations and examples, I can see that the counter is , for instance, initialised with a name in the `open` of a map function.

But in my case I can not initialise the counter as I will need one per eventId and I do not know the value in advance. Also, I understand how expensive it would be to create a new counter every time an even passes in the `map()` method of the MapFunction.
Finally, I can not keep a "cache" of counters as it would be too big.

Ideally, I would like something like this :

```
class Event(id: String, name: String)

class ExampleMapFunction extends RichMapFunction[Event, Event] {
  @transient private var counter: Counter = _

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    counter = new Counter()
  }

  override def map(event: Event): Event = {
    counter.inc(event.id)
    event
  }
}
```

Or basically could I implement my own counter that allow me to pass a dimension? if yes, how?

Any advise or best practice for this kind of use-case?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use metrics for this instead of keyed state (which would seem to be the obvious answer)? Metrics don't really scale all that well.

Comment: For monitoring reasons, I want to do check in every steps of my topology. For example, since I have many joins of streams, I want to know where it won't join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If keeping a cache of the counters would be too big, then I don't think using metrics is going to scale in a way that will satisfy your requirements.

A few alternatives:

- Use side outputs to collect meaningful events in some external, queryable/visualizable data store -- e.g., influxdb.
- Hold the info in keyed state, and use broadcast messages to trigger output of relevant portions of it as desired (again using side outputs).
- Hold the info in keyed state, and take periodic savepoints, which you then analyze via queries using the state processor API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
When I say "it would be too big", it's mainly because it will never stop increasing (auto generated ids).
I will dig into these propositions, though what about using an external library such as https://github.com/Netflix/spectator/ ?