# Simple metrics with name/key not defined previously

Tags: apache-flink

I just want to emit metrics with simple key and its value at current timestamp - Is there a way to do this? I see flink only has meter, counter and gauges which has to be created first with a key and then you emit values. But I do not want to define anything like this - just emit key and its value at current time.

Please let me know if this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: What is the cardinality of the "simple key"?

Comment: Not sure how to define cardinality of this but this is what i want to do: 
metrics.emit("baz", 0);
metrics.emit("baz", 1)
metrics.emit("foo", 1);
key above is not already defined like we have to do currently using meter, gauge, counter, etc

Comment: This is somewhat similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456830/how-to-use-multiple-counters-in-flink/58457185#58457185 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56694833/how-to-create-dynamic-metric-in-flink.

Comment: Thanks David! yeah seems very similar but not sure if i can use output tags. But thanks a lot for pointing this out!!

Comment: The reason I asked about cardinality (number of unique key values) is that I think you can dynamically define metrics values, but you don't want to do that if you'd wind up with many (more than a few hundred?) unique values.

Comment: yeah, there can be many such keys thats why i was avoiding creating separate meter/gauge just to emit one simple key and value but it seems there is no alternative today